# Sync stripper circuit for RGsB to RGBHV converter

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, video, synchronization

Currently, I have a RGsB signal source, ISL59885 sync separator and RGBHV monitor. Green is the same on the input and output connector (meaning, sync-on-green, not the perfect clean green signal).

From my sync separator I get HSYNC, VSYNC and CSYNC. If I understand correctly, my "Gs" signal is nothing but Green signal + CSYNC. So in order to get a clean Green signal, I need to do "Gs - CSYNC". Am I right? I'm a newbie in analog circuit design, so I have no idea how to achieve this. I believe this should have been solved many times, but all schematics for sync strippers are based on Op Amps, or maybe I'm just not using the correct terms to search for it.

Maybe there exists a sync separator with clean output? The closest thing to what I want, that I have found is this application note on using ISL4089: [TB462](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/oth/tb462-simple-circuit-removes-sync-tip).

Comment: the monitor hopefully will have a black clamp and do it for you. Realise the sync signals won’t be visible anyways.

Comment: @Kartman My monitor is doing a good job ignoring these extra sync signals on the green channel. However, I want my conversion circuitry to do RGsB->RGBHV, not RGsB->RGsBHV, so I want to pass the R and B lines unmodified, but strip the sync signals from G.